# How to start with Selenium and TeamCity integration?

Tags: selenium

I am basically from Testing and I know QTP Automation, but now my client is asking to do some analysis and start with pilot project as auotmate the teamcity tests using Selenium.

But I am really not aware of Teamcity as well Selinum functionalities, as per the googled info I came to know as Teamcity is Java based application for continuous build integration and Selenium to automate applications using JScript/Java Code.

Please some one can clarify this in details, how this will work and how we can start & finish this activity successfully.

Thanks,
PSR

Comment: Hi, Subbarao, have you checked on Stack Overflow? I found several questions about TeamCity integration with Selenium there, including some details of how to implement an integrated test automation flow.

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and compare TeamCity to Jenkins and make sure you choose TeamCity only if Jenkins is unable to do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

@Subbarao: These links may help for you,  [Link1](https://docs.saucelabs.com/ci-integrations/teamcity/), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524159/automate-selenium-tests-on-teamcity-continuous-integration-server) and [Link3](http://joellubrano.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/integrating-sauce-labs-selenium-tests-with-a-teamcity-integrated-server/)